# Уменьшенная копия фотографии на PHP

Tags: php

Как создать уменьшенную копию загружаемой картинки на php? Может есть что-то более удобное, чем php?

Comment: да, фотошоп :)

Comment: Ага, были бы все пользователи такие сознательные, тогда не было бы проблем))

Comment: да `<img src="img.jpg" width="100" />` высоту не указывать! Но при этом вес будет орегинален)

Comment: Вот поэтому и ищу решение, так как хочу сэкономить трафик юзеров

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это типовая задача. Решается с помощью [imagecopyresized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) (GD). Пример из мануала:

```
<?php
// Имя файла и масштаб
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Тип содержимого
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Получение новых размеров
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Загрузка
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Масштабирование
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Вывод
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```